# Which way to go?

Tags: probability

Given an **m** x **n** grid,

How many ways are there to go from *upper left corner* to the *lower right one*?

You can only move right and down, not up or left.

Numerical solution are:

- m=2, n=2, solution=6
- m=3, n=4, solution=35
- m=5, n=6, solution=462

Comment: How might you write down an individual "way"?

Comment: Why ? Do you feel “lost” ? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a move to the right be R, and a move downwards be D. Think of writting down each solution as a string of D's and R's, which basically indicates the order of the steps taken. For example, RDRD means Right -> Down -> Right -> Down.

The problem then reduces (by the bijective principle, if you fancy)  to counting the number of permutations of a string with M number of R's and N number of D's in it, of which there are $\binom{m+n}{n} = \binom{m+n}{m}$ permutations.

For example, for the $3$x$2$ case, the number of ways is the number of permutations of the string RRRDD, which is $\binom{5}{2}=\binom{5}{3}=10$.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\binom {m+n}{n}$, this is the way to get the answers. It's a common problem to the problem how to get from point $ (0,0) $ to point $ (m,n) $ which can be done using the idea of indistinguishable objects in distinguishable boxes.